# Seek the partial derivative

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative

How to seek the partial derivative of the following formula

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}a^{\top}XB(I+BXB)^{-1}B^{\top}X^{\top}a$, where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $I \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $x$ is a parameter in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that matrices scare you. Actually, just apply the product rule
$$\begin{align}&(a^TXB(I+BXB)^{-1}B^TX^Ta)'\\
=&a^TX'B(I+BXB)^{-1}B^TX^Ta+a^TXB[(I+BXB)^{-1}]'B^TX^Ta+a^TXB(I+BXB)^{-1}B^TX'^Ta
\end{align}$$
and then chain rule
$$\begin{align}[(I+BXB)^{-1}]'&=-(I+BXB)^{-1}(I+BXB)'(I+BXB)^{-1}\\&
=-(I+BXB)^{-1}BX'B(I+BXB)^{-1}\end{align}$$
The answer is now obvious.